# How does FILE stream buffer work?

Tags: c, buffer

I understand `fopen()` opens file and creates a buffer for read and write operations on that file. `fopen()` returns a pointer for that buffer.

So my question is, in the code below, the `_copy` function body has a `temp` matrix to transfer between the `fread()` and `fwrite()`. why cant I directly transfer from buffer to buffer?

```
/* example: copyfile.exe xxxxx.txt   zzzzzz.txt */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFF 8192
void _copy(FILE *source, FILE *destination);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;  // fp1 source file pointer// fp2 copied file pointer 

    if (argc !=3 )           //command line must have 3 arguments
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s (source file) (copy file)\n", argv[0][0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((fp1 = fopen(argv[1], "rb")) == NULL)    //Opening source file
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n",argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if((fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "ab+")) == NULL)  //Opening destination file
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not create %s \n",argv[2]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if( setvbuf(fp1,NULL, _IOFBF, BUFF) != 0) //Setting buffer for source file
    {
        fputs("Can't create output buffer\n", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if( setvbuf(fp2,NULL, _IOFBF, BUFF) != 0) //Setting buffer for destination file
    {
        fputs("Can't create input buffer\n", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    _copy(fp1, fp2);  
    if (ferror(fp1)!=0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file %s\n", argv[1]);
    if(ferror(fp2)!=0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Error writing file %s\n",argv[2]);
    printf("Done coping %s (source) to %s (destination) \n",argv[1], argv[2]);
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    return (0);
}

void _copy(FILE  *source, FILE *destination)
{
    size_t bytes;
    static char temp[BUFF];

    while((bytes = fread(temp,sizeof(char),BUFF,source))>0)
        fwrite(temp,sizeof(char),bytes,destination);
}
```

Comment: No, `fopen()` does not return a buffer, it returns a `FILE` pointer. `FILE` is an opaque structure. You cannot do anything with a `FILE` pointer exept pass it to the different `f...` functions such as `fread`, `fwrite`, `fclose` and a few others.

Comment: @MichaelWalz so its can't be transferred from the read file buffer to the write file buffer directly? this temp matrix is necessary?

Comment: @topcat, that is correct. There is no `fcopy(FILE *src, FILE *dst)` function in the standard C library. There are lots of ways to write it, depending upon the needs of the program as well as various other conditions to consider. This is left to the programmer. The source you show has one such implementation. Another common way is to [loop on `fgetc` and `fputc`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-copy-contents-one-file-another-file/) and let the C library handle all of the data buffering.

Comment: @lurker looping through the while file using `fgetc`and `fputc` is most likely slower that copying large chunks of data using `fread`/`fwrite`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz no doubt. I was just saying that there are multiple approaches which can be found and not offering comment on efficiency.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I deleted my comment, it wasn't very clear. I was referencing this from [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite): "If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero)". This code totally ignores the return value of `fwrite()`, which is a larger worry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the underlying buffer from a FILE * in another FILE *. As you were told in comment, FILE * is an opaque pointer. But you can avoid the overhead of copying data between buffers by forcing both files in non buffered mode:

```
setbuf(fp, NULL);   // cause the stream to be unbuffered
```